# вложенный запрос в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Обычный запрос выполнить как-то так:

```
rn = meta.objects.filter(rid=form.cleaned_data['day'])
```

равен

```
select * from [meta] where rid = :day
```

Никак не могу понять как реализовать вот такой запрос:

```
select [rid]
     , [hn]
     , [no]
     , [to]
     , [te]
     , cast([cmd] as varchar(100)) as [cmd]
     , [tiev]
     , [tyev]
     , [d]
     , [s]
from [meta] as [tmcl]
where [tiev] = (select max([tiev])
                from [meta]
                where [no] = [tmcl].[no]
                      and [db] = [tmcl].[db]
                      and [srv] = [tmcl].[srv]
                      and isnull([tyev], 0) = 0
                      and convert(date, [tiev]) >= (convert(date, getdate() - :day)))
order by [tiev] desc
```

или выполнить процедуру и получить данные

```
exec meta_proc 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import connection

c = connection.cursor()
try:
    c.callproc('meta_proc', (1,))
    r = c.fetchall()
    if r:
        # Обработка полученных данных
finally:
    c.close()
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors)